# Blacklisted items

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have been trying to update my Ubuntu but whenever I click on `Upgrade`, my system does the usual checks and tells me it can only do a "Partial install" which, when I accept returns this error:

```
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade:
The package 'unity-2d' is marked for removal but it is in the 
removal blacklist.
```

How do I resolve it? I have rev 12.04 LTS installed

As requested, the output of  (1) `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` (2) `for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done` (3) `sudo apt-get update` (4) `apt-get -s upgrade` and (5) `apt-get -s dist-upgrade` are shown [in this pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1664587/).

Comment: Hi Eliah to cut and paste the terminal reply just for the first command would be a number of screens as its telling me that the number of characters is to long

Comment: Think Ive done it right

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1664587/plain/ is the down load

Answer (score 2):

#### Debian software sources may give wrong package versions, with wrong dependencies.

Wrong for Ubuntu, that is. (Similarly, Ubuntu software sources may cause problems on Debian.)

From the information you provided, the most likely cause of the problem is probably that you have Debian software sources enabled:

```
deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stable main
deb-src http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stable main
```

If you disable them, that may solve the problem. To do that, first back up `sources.list`:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old
```

Then edit it:

- Graphically, with `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources/list`, *or*
- in the terminal, with: `sudo nano -w /etc/apt/sources.list`

Find those two lines and add `#` to the beginning so they read:

```
#deb http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stable main
#deb-src http://ftp.se.debian.org/debian stable main
```

Then save the file, quit the text editor, and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

See if the problem is fixed.

*If you deliberately added those software sources and installed software from those repositories, then please edit your question to provide details, so I can give information about how to use the software (if possible) without causing problems. It is possible to enable a repository but configure it so it's only used for a couple packages.*

#### You have many non-working PPAs.

This is less likely to be causing the current problem, but I recommend fixing this. It's worth fixing itself, and at least it will no longer obscure whatever is causing the problem.

- [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

#### If you do these things, and the problem isn't fixed, please provide more information.

You posted only incomplete output from `apt-get -s upgrade` and `apt-get -s dist-upgrade`, since the output was too large to fit in the Terminal window.

So, run these commands instead:

```
cd ~
apt-get -s upgrade &> simulated-upgrade.log
apt-get -s dist-upgrade &> simulated-dist-upgrade.log
```

Then open `simulated-upgrade.log` in a text editor (it's in your home folder), copy its contents to the clipboard, paste it at http://paste.ubuntu.com, and provide the link. Do the same thing for `simulated-dist-upgrade.log`. (The best way to provide both links is to edit your question.)

Comment: Like last time you have saved the day its worked fine Thank you for the much appreciated help .... Stan